# Using pre-cut floss on Shabbos, if the floss is likely to shred

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, health-safety-shmira, teeth

Please imagine:

- You floss daily, and your gums never bleed.
- You've pre-cut a good length of floss before Shabbos.

However:

- Every time you floss, the floss [shreds](https://www.thousandoaksfamilydentistry.com/blog/dental-questions-why-do-my-teeth-shred-floss).

In such a case, are you allowed to floss on the Sabbath? Why or why not?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.314.41?lang=bi&with=all

Comment: @שלום: Thank you! But the Hebrew is not so easy for me to understand. You can log into Sefaria and [add a translation](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/483970.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20contribute,translation%20and%20click%20%22Save%22.) of the paragraph, if you'd like.

Comment: This translates into "One may unbraid or cut because severing a string is permitted for an item that is detached (grom the ground), as mentioned above in 7. There is also no prohibition of mechateich since one is not particular about the size."

Answer (score 3):

It is allowed.

R' Dovid Ribiat writes:

> *Mechatech* is only transgressed when the measured cutting is intentional and calculated. ... **It entails only deliberately measured
> cutting.**

(Source: [*The 39 Melochos*](https://www.feldheim.com/the-39-melochos-1). Volume 3. Page 936.)

It is not *koraya* either:

> Cutting a length of thread, string or rope to a specific length ...
> would not be *koraya* at all, because **it doesn't apply to these
> items**

(*Ibid.* Page 938.)

As such, R' Daniel Braude writes that **it is permitted to floss if the person doesn't usually bleed and if the floss is pre-cut before Shabbat**. Otherwise one has to use it on the roll.

(Source: [*Learn Shabbos in 3 Minutes a Day*](https://www.feldheim.com/learn-shabbos-in-just-3-minutes-a-day). Page 350.)