# Removing plaque from floss: is this borer?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, borer-separating, teeth

## Background

Flossing is okay on Shabbat, **if and only if:** you don't usually bleed, and the floss is pre-cut before Shabbat. [(Source.)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136586/using-pre-cut-floss-on-shabbos-if-the-floss-is-likely-to-shred#136592)

Please imagine:  Your hand-eye coordination is not the best.  You were never picked first for sports teams as a kid.

## My question

When you floss your teeth, plaque (biofilm) sticks to the floss.  Instead of winding to a fresh section of floss, you customarily wipe the plaque off the exposed floss.  You use your fingers to do so.

Does this violate the Shabbat prohibition of [*borer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/39_Melakhot#Sorting/purification)? After all, you are removing unwanted plaque from wanted floss.

## Related

[Removing plaque from floss: is the plaque muktzeh?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/140569/removing-plaque-from-floss-is-the-plaque-muktzeh)

Comment: No more than wiping food off a plate.

Comment: related: [Using pre-cut floss on Shabbos, if the floss is likely to shred](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/136592/11501)