# Removing plaque from floss: is the plaque muktzeh?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, muktzeh, teeth

## Background

Flossing is okay on Shabbat, **if and only if:** you don't usually bleed, and the floss is pre-cut before Shabbat. [(Source.)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136586/using-pre-cut-floss-on-shabbos-if-the-floss-is-likely-to-shred#136592)

Please imagine:  Your hand-eye coordination is not the best.  You were never picked first for sports teams as a kid.

## My question

When you floss your teeth, plaque (biofilm) sticks to the floss.  Instead of winding to a fresh section of floss, you customarily wipe the plaque off the exposed floss.  You use your fingers to do so.

Does this violate the Shabbat prohibition of moving [muktze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muktzeh) items?  After all, you are moving plaque, which has no Shabbat use.

## Related

[Removing plaque from floss: is this borer?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/140568/removing-plaque-from-floss-is-this-borer)

Comment: [H. Shabboth 26:13](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=12&perek=26&halocha=13&hilite=) seems relevant here.

Comment: @Deuteronomy:  I looked at a [translation](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbath.26.13?lang=bi) of Mishneh Torah Sabbath 26:13.  Sure, you can discard the plaque.  But you don't have to touch the plaque directly in order to do so.  You could just discard the entire piece of floss.

Comment: "you can discard the plaque... You could just discard the entire piece of floss" Either way is fine to my understanding. I think most people would prefer not to touch the filth (in this case biofilm/plaque), but should they, doing so would not be problematic to my reading.

Comment: related: [Using pre-cut floss on Shabbos, if the floss is likely to shred](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/136592/11501)