# A few days before Shabbat, you folded up some pre-cut waxed floss and stuck it to itself. Can you unstick it during Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, health-safety-shmira, teeth

## Background

Flossing is okay on Shabbat, **if and only if:** you don't usually bleed, and the floss is pre-cut before Shabbat. [(Source.)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136586/using-pre-cut-floss-on-shabbos-if-the-floss-is-likely-to-shred#136592)

Please imagine:  Several days before Shabbat began, you pre-cut a few long pieces of waxed floss.  Waxed floss is slightly sticky.  You folded up each long string several times and stuck it tightly to itself.  This made each piece into a neat and tidy little bundle.

## My question

Separating items which were stuck together is sometimes forbidden on Shabbat.  Please see [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2016/07/disposable-diapers-shabbos-2/#:%7E:text=The%20potential%20problem,le%2Dhiskayem).) and [here](https://outorah.org/p/6553/#:%7E:text=When%20a%20melacha,untie%20it%2C%20either.).

Are you allowed to unstick floss bundles during Shabbat, in order so that you can unfold and use them?